# 'OLS' object has no attribute 'summary'

Tags: python, pandas, least-squares

I'm posting this question for those who ran into the same issue I ran into:

When trying to fit my data like so, and printing the result:

```py
import statsmodel.api as sm
model = sm.OLS(df['SalePrice'], df.drop(['SalePrice'], axis=1))
print(model.summary())
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'OLS' object has no attribute 'summary'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution was to add `.fit()`:

```py
import statsmodel.api as sm
model = sm.OLS(df['SalePrice'], df.drop(['SalePrice'], axis=1)).fit()
print(model.summary())
```